Change background color of individual array cells in math mode
How do I change the background colour of one cell in an array? For example, How could I do this for a few individual cells in the following code? Most of the answers seem more relevant to using array in TikZ. Is the approach similar?
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{ccc}
    1&2&3\\
    a&b&c\\
    A&B&C
\end{array}\]
\end{document}


I think you're looking for \cellcolor, a macro provided by the colortbl package.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \fi
\usepackage{xcolor}   % various pre-defined named colors
\usepackage{colortbl} % for '\cellcolor' command
\usepackage{array}    % for '\extrarowheight' length parameter
\begin{document}

\[
\addtolength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & 2 & \cellcolor{yellow!50} 3 \\
    a & b & c \\
    \cellcolor{lightgray!50} A & B & C
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}

